# json_encode Returning a PHP Array

Tags: php, json

So I am working with PHP to pass a PHP array over a jQuery Ajax request to another PHP page. This is quite the task. For some reason, my json_encode is returning an array instead of a string, I am not quite sure why. Here is my PHP code:

```
$new_spreadsheet = nl2br($_POST['spreadsheet']);
$new_spreadsheet = explode('<br />', $new_spreadsheet);
array_shift($new_spreadsheet);
$new_spreadsheet = array_values($new_spreadsheet);
echo json_encode($new_spreadsheet);
```

I would show you the output, but it is really long. Basically this is outputting a PHP array which consists of each row on the spreadsheet. This is what I want to have, but the problem is that I don't want the quotes and everything in the array. I am pretty sure I need to run json_decode, but when I do that my code returns an error saying that the parameter needs to be a string. I can tell something is not right, but am not quite sure what I need to change. I would appreciate any advice.

Update: At this point, when I try to loop through the array and print each value, the first array index is equal to a double quote like so: ". There are double quotes in random values throughout the area. I am not quite sure about what is causing this.

If I echo the rows from within the json_encoded PHP array onto the console, I get the following output:

```
"
correct value
correct value
correct value
"
```

Comment: What quotes in the array don't you want? The ones required by the JSON specification? You'd deal with them by parsing the JSON on the client, not in the PHP that is creating the JSON.

Comment: why do you convert your linebreaks to `<br />` forth and back?

Comment: @Quentin, I am working on trying to explain that. Once I get a good explanation on it I will edit my post. Hopefully it will make more sense to you then.

Comment: @RaphaelMüller, what do you mean?

Comment: why don't you just explode with the `PHP_EOL` instead of inserting `<br />` with `nl2br` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using JSON, which means you have to adhere to somewhat more stringent syntax rules than Javascript's. e.g.

```
<?php

$arr = array('This' => 'is', 'an' => 'array in php');
echo json_encode($array);

?>
```

output:

```
{"This":"is","an":"array in PHP"}
```

There is **NO** way to avoid getting quotes on the values, as they're a fundamental requirement of JSON (and Javascript). If you don't want quotes, then don't use JSON.

Comment: I don't think you understood what I meant. Basically I am getting an array returned with array "values" which consist OF quotes. Like so:

Comment: then your explode isn't working right, and your entire "array" is just a string. What does `var_dump($new_spreadsheet)` look like at each stage of your code?

Comment: when I use var_dump, I am seeing that it is returning a string. I guess now the question is how I change it into an array after passing the value through a PHP request. Do I use json_decode()?

Comment: No idea, since you haven't explained at all what your inputs are.

Comment: You said you're getting: {"Some Index":"""} - so you're getting a quote, inside quotes, in your JSON output?

Comment: if it is `"""`, then something is VERY wrong, because that's illegal json, and should NEVER be produced by PHP like that. Unless that text contains HTML and you're outputting it in a browser.

Answer (score -2):

try only br.

```
$new_spreadsheet = explode("<br>", $new_spreadsheet);
```

It will work. and json_enode can never return an array. try var_dump and check.Also make sure before you post, use htmlspecialcharacters.